# How to acces my EEL app from the internet?

Tags: python, reverse-proxy, bottle, nginx-reverse-proxy, eel

I have my EEL app running great in my LAN, and I would like to get an acces from the internet with my nginx reverse proxy (letsencrypt docker image).

I saw that EEl use a bottle server and that I probably need a middleware script to pass the right header to my app.

I don't know how to handle with that I saw this code in the bottle faq but I have no idea how to use it ...

```
  def fixed_app(environ, start_response):
    environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'
    environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] = 'example.com'
    return app(environ, start_response)
  return https_app

app = bottle.default_app()
app.wsgi = fix_environ_middleware(app.wsgi)
```

Can someone help me with that ? I feel that I'm close of my objective

Thanks